# Checking if category exists in a MYSQLI table column with a csv value format

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get all of the products where it has the category that I wanted. The problem is, in the products table, the column "category" in it has a value in csv format (e.g., "Edibles,Beverages,Topicals"). How would I going to check if the category that I wanted exists in the category column?

This is what I have so far

```
$category = $_POST["category"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '$category' ORDER BY rand()";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$productsArray = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Absolutely never do this. Use the mysqli library itself to fill in values for queries, don't just throw them into a string and thing that'll do. People_will_ try to call your form with a `category='; drop table users;` as POST data.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: No worries about that. This is in the admin panel

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to achieve what I want?

Comment: If it's in an admin panel, that is _even more worrying_, change that ASAP. It's not enough work to say "no I'd prefer to keep doing things wrong", get in the habit of writing secure sql querying code and never look back. It's simple code. As for solving your problem, read up on which operators you can use in WHERE clauses. In this case, [IN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIKE statement, in case not all categories are stored in one row.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category LIKE ('%".$category."%') ORDER BY rand()";
```

Comment: please don't advocate just "putting a string in a string", this is not how you safely query a database, let alone how you safely query a database in PHP. Use https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php